Royal-Sloan flushometer leak at vaccum breaker area
Lately when the valve is flushed, a slight trickle of water runs down the pipe from the vacuum breaker closet nut to the toilet spud nut. tightening the upper nut did not remedy.
Could it be a faulty vacuum breaker?
